# Rules for (hydro)chlorination of double and triple carbon bonds

Tags: reaction-mechanism

If $\ce{HCl}$ is added in a compound with both double and triple bond the double bond breaks and gets chlorinated.

If $\ce{Cu2Cl2}$ and $\ce{NH4Cl}$ are also present then which bond will get chlorinated, the double or triple bond?